# Filtering data in dplyr by multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, dataset

Here are my dummy data

```
    year <- c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022)
    individual <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
    group <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B")
    mass <- c(84.3, 82.5, 80.6, 79.2, 82.8, 79.1, 82.6)
    dataset <- data.frame(year, individual, group, mass)
```

I have 10 years of body mass data for individual birds across two "groups". As you'll see from the dummy dataset, I have instances where there exists mass data for one group but not the other (individual 1, year 2013). I want to only include data where I have an individual's mass for BOTH 'group A' AND 'group B'. I just can't figure out how to filter data this way--ideally with dplyr's filter() command.

I apologize if this is somewhat of a duplicate of another post, I just can't find an answer that helps me do this precise filtering task.

```
    df2 <- dataset %>%
      group_by(individual, year) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

^ I used this code to group data by individual within each year such that it only includes individuals that appear more than once (an individual can only appear once per group per year). However, from here I couldn't figure out how to exclude any instances where I have a third row of mass data for an individual in a subsequent year for either Group A or B, but not both. I need a dataset that only includes individuals where I have BOTH Group A and Group B mass values in a given year.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the desired output from these sample data?

Comment: Do you mean *mass data for both groups for an individual in the same year*? In other words, your desired output from your dummy data is only the first two rows?

Comment: `dataset %>%filter(all(c('A', 'B') %in% group), .by = c(year, individual))`

Comment: @Onyambu you should consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Onyambu This is exactly what I'm looking for! It's not posted as an answer though so I can't mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ASAPScramz now it is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
dataset %>%
  filter(all(c('A', 'B') %in% group), .by = c(year, individual))
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to only include data where I have an individual's mass for BOTH 'group A' AND 'group B'. I just can't figure out how to filter data this way--ideally with dplyr's filter() command.

I think a possible solution is to `pivot_wider` your data.

```r
dataset |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = mass, names_prefix = "mass") 
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>    year individual massA massB
#>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2012          1  84.3  82.5
#> 2  2013          1  80.6  NA  
#> 3  2019          2  79.2  NA  
#> 4  2020          2  NA    82.8
#> 5  2021          3  79.1  NA  
#> 6  2022          3  NA    82.6
```

Now you can apply `|> na.omit()` or `dplyr::filter(!is.na(massA) & !is.na(massB))`/`tidyr::drop_na(massA, massB)`, group your data, ...

> I need a dataset that only includes individuals where I have BOTH Group A and Group B mass values in a given year.

Like

```r
dataset |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = group, 
                     values_from = mass, 
                     names_prefix = "mass") |>
  na.omit()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>    year individual massA massB
#>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2012          1  84.3  82.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Using pivot_wider() followed by omitting NA's indeed works but it would involve backtracking (probably with pivot_longer()) to get "Group" back into one column for a repeatability analysis that I'm trying to do. I appreciate this response as well but I think I got the most streamline answer from @Onyambu.